# How to get id from checkbox onchange event

Tags: java, html, servlets

This is my servlet page.I am trying to get brand id from checkbox onchange event. but it wont work. Can anyone help me please.

```
public class servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try {
            Session s1 = Connection.NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Criteria c = s1.createCriteria(Brand.class);
            List<Brand> list = c.list();
            for (Brand brand : list) {
                PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\"> <onchange=\"self.location.href=index.jsp?b=" + brand.getIdbrand() + ">" + brand.getName() + "<br>");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you have to write some Javascript code to implement that, try some codes from google to get it.

Comment: @KhAnSaHaB thanx sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at your `<input>` tag.

```
"<input type=\"checkbox\"> <onchange=\"self.location.href=index.jsp?b=" + 
brand.getIdbrand() + ">"
```

**You have accidently closed the input tag in the middle. `onchange` is an attribute of `<input>`**, so it should be in the `<input>` tag. And there's a missing double quotation `"` at the end. Change it like this,

```
"<input type='checkbox' onchange='self.location.href=\"index.jsp?b=" + 
brand.getIdbrand() + "\"'>"
```